# Android: Two different events for single tap and long press/double tap?

Tags: android, events, listener, tap

I am trying to develop a feature where a single tap of an item will call an Intent to go to another Activity, and a long press OR double tap of the item does something else, such as allow you to edit the text.

So far I am only able to get both to happen at the same time but not individually. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(e);
}


public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) { 
    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), SecondClass.class);
    getContext().startActivity(i);

    return true; 
}

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) { return false; }
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Edit feature here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Postsomecode, so i can rectify it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. It turned out all I needed to do is change the return value from `false` to `true` in the `onDown()` handler.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return gestureScanner.onTouchEvent(e);
}

public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) { 

    Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), SecondClass.class);
    getContext().startActivity(i);

    return true; 
}

public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) { return true; }


public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Edit Feature", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use a GestureDetector, the [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) has the methods that you want with `onSingleTapConfirmed()`, `onLongPress()`, and `onDoubleTap()`.

Comment: I have been using a GestureDetector. If I put my Intent in the onSingleTapConfirmed() method it doesn't do anything. It just makes the onLongPress() work on a single tap :

Comment: What type of View are you adding this to? It looks like you want a TextView that can become an EditText on a long-click.