# How to disable onclick listener while swiping a view in android?

Tags: android

I have a view that can be swiped to another page. It has an onClick listener, which displays a dialog box.

The problem is, swiping triggers both actions (i.e. It shows the next page and the dialog box).

How can I disable the onClick listener when swiping.

Comment: @ADR Slow down. Some of the edit that you are suggesting are frivolous: changing "I'm trying to" into "I want to" and this one is a grammatical mess: "I'm have a view, while swiping, it will displays another page."

Comment: Nice. That is of course what he wrote to this forum for was to get his grammar checked. Why not offer a suggestion to his problem instead of knit-picking his grammar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a GestureDetector ([as well](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13324250/1267661)), the [SimpleOnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html) has `onSingleTapConfirmed()` for click events and `onFling()` for swipe events.

Comment: Now i need to get the view inside onSingleTapConfirmed(). How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please post your relevant code in your question so I can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

While `onClick` of `swipelayout` put `swipelayout.getSurfaceView()` and while swiping it triggers only swipe action. See the code below:

```
holder.swipeLayout.getSurfaceView().setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Do your onClick stuff here..
    }
}
```